# Código no imprime la matriz de la imagen con opencv y numpy

Tags: python, opencv

Debería imprimir la matriz con los números de los píxeles de la imagen.¿Por qué no lo hace?

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
thanos = cv2.imread("thanos_1200x1200.jpg",0)
print(thanos)
```

Comment: ¿No imprime nada? ¿Qué imprime en su lugar? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: no he trabajado demasiado con opencv y no sé que es el segundo parámetro, pero yo lo hago simplemente con `cv.imread("imagen.jpe")`